# Keras data augmentation issue

Tags: python, keras, data-augmentation

I'm following a tutorial and some answers here, but can't get data augmentation to work. See the image below.

I'd expect more rotated images to show up, i tested very small and large values but none seem too work.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! [Please do not upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Also refer to the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Comment: Data augmentation layers are not active during inference, you need to pass `training=True` to the model call.